# FiPy interior conducting boundary conditions

Tags: python, fipy

I am a newcomer to FiPy and I am solving the Poisson's equation for the potential inside a 3D volume. It works fine for surface boundary conditions but now I need to place a conductor inside. This will be a constant potential surface and I realize that you cannot use potential.constrain for interior surfaces.

The documentation suggests using an ImplicitSourceTerm along with a mask defining the surface, but it is not evident how this can be used to constrain the potential to be constant, or equivalently to constrain the electric field to be perpendicular to the surface. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The discussion at http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#applying-internal-boundary-conditions describes exactly what you are trying to do. I think I know why it might not have worked for you, though. When declaring an `ImplicitSourceTerm`, FiPy has to be careful not to add negative values to the diagonal of the matrix, so it examines the signs of the coefficients of the `ImplicitSourceTerm` and compares them to the signs of the diagonal elements form the `DiffusionTerm` (and others) that have already been put in the matrix; if the signs are opposite, then FiPy treats those cells explicitly (puts everything on the RHS vector).

If you declare your equation (like I initially did) as

```
eq = (fp.DiffusionTerm(coeff=dielectric) + charge ==   
      conductor * largeValue * conductorPotential
      - fp.ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=conductor * largeValue)
```

then everything about the conductor gets put on the RHS vector and the implicit solver never "sees" it. If you reverse the order of the last two terms, then `conductor * largeValue` gets put on the matrix diagonal and `conductor * largeValue * conductorPotential` gets put on the RHS and the solution for these cells becomes dominated by `conductorPotential`.

In short, what I'm saying is that it matters (to FiPy (in this case)) whether you say

```
V == conductorPotential
```

or

```
conductorPotential == V
```

I posted an IPython notebook at https://gist.github.com/guyer/a61d5adfa9a050eb970a

Comment: Thank you for your response and your clear iPython notebook example.
In my particular case the problem was not the order of the terms. I am dealing with large potentials (10^5) and because of this I set largeValue = 10^15. This gives nonsensical results. However, I found that setting largeValue = 10^10 gives reasonable results. Looks like I created an overflow somewhere.